# how code is executed and gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, compilation

I'm very interesting in compilation and I've got a question about gcc.

I know that a tree is generated from the code to compile, then ASM code is
generated and I need some explanations about this point.

ASM code is added in a file and executed later or ASM code is directly loaded in memory with **asm** functions ?  I'm working on a small compiler and I don't know how to execute the tree generated, and I didn't find any documentation about that.

Comment: Do you want to know how GCC does it, or how *you* can do this?

Comment: How GCC does and how I can do this the easiest way.

Comment: Please first learn about [assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) and [machine code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code). That will help you ask a better question and perhaps even let you answer it yourself.

Comment: you are long way from the "loader" dude :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC's front-end parses the source files in different languages (C, C++, Fortran, ObjectiveC, Java etc.). Then the code (AST) is translated to internal representation, the [RTL (register transfer language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_transfer_language). This is a close-to-assembly representation.

Then this RTL code is transformed to target machine's assembly and written to .o (object) file.

The linker then combines generated .o-files to the executable.

The "inline" assembly snippets are also supported by GCC in C/C++.

The workflow is

```
Source file -> 
 AST  ->
  RTL representation  ->
   machine codes (with _optional_ text output of the ASM code) ->
    Executable (produced by linker)
```

For the interpreter you may directly interpret the AST or produce you own opcodes for the virtual machine since such an interpreter (virtual machine) would be simpler than the AST interpreter.

If you want all the details you should look at [LCC (with a book by Chris Fraser and David Hanson)](https://sites.google.com/site/lccretargetablecompiler/). All the details of code generation for real-world architectures are provided in the accompanying book.

And to know what can be done with the generated code you should read the [Linkers and Loaders by John Levine](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

Finally, to avoid asking everything about scripting/interpreters, refer to [Game Scripting Mastery by Alex Varanese](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Game_scripting_mastery.html?id=q5jdl_LLreMC&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Where do GIMPLE and SSA fit into this picture?

Comment: SSA is a tool to optimize and another intermediate representation. Yes, it all fits in the same workflow. I just omitted the optimization step.

Comment: I don't know much about the newer GIMPLE (but it also is an IR). There are many LLVM/Clang adepts on StackOverflow, look for the LLVM info. It is clean and clear, but "a little huge", as any other real-world project.

Answer (score 2):

Quite vague a question, and I don't think I fully understood what your exact problem is, but here you are an answer anyway: assembly is not put in the executable. Assembly is written to an intermediate assembly file, from which the assembler generates true binary machine code (called an object file), then the linker merges them (along with the needed libraries) to the final executable. When the application is run, the executable is loaded directly into the RAM by the OS and executed natively by the processor.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to put the assembly code in a file, I thought I have to use __asm___() to execute directly ASM.

Comment: @lilawood ah so that's what you are asking about! No. You can use the `__asm__` **directive** (it's *not* a function), but all it does is that it tells GCC to copy its arguments verbatim to the generated assembly file.

Comment: Doesn't GCC skip the "human readable assembly code" stage completely, unless you pass `-S` in the command line?

Comment: @harold no, it doesn't. It can't generate machine code directly. That's why binutils and GAS is there.

Comment: @harold it's not something to be fixed. Parser/compiler logic *should* be separated from messing with binary files. Trust the GNU people, although their coding style is a complete mess, their semantics have been proven quite good so far :)

Comment: Well I'm not advocating the abandonment of Separation of Concerns, but that trick works just as well if you keep it in different parts of the same program, but it's less messy that way. Meanwhile, many other compilers skip the useless "human readable assembly" stage, and that doesn't appear to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

HOW A SOURCE CODE TRANSLATED TO EXECUTABLE CODE ?
We provide Source Code to the compiler and it gives us Executable code .But this is not a single step operation .This follow some predefined steps to convert the Source Code to Executable Code.

**steps followed for conversion from source code to executable code**

**1.Preprocessor**
It is very useful part of the compiler as it does lots of job before translated to machine code. It is a text processor which dose the below text editing operation

It removes the comment lines in source code which are written in the Source code for more readability/easy understanding .
    It add the content of header files to the source code. Header files always contains function prototypes and declarations.(Header files never contain any executable code )
    A very important property of Preprocessor is Conditional Compile. It is very required for scalable design. This property also remove the unnecessary burden from compiler.
    Macros are replaced by this preprocessor.

The final output of this stage is known as pure C code.

**2.Translator**
This part of complier is responsible for converting of pure C code to assembly language code.
Step by step mapping of C language code to assembly language code done here.
The prototypes of the functions and declarations are used by this part for translation of C code.
The out put of this stage known as assembly code.

**3.Assembler**
It generate Object code from assembly language code.It converts the assembly language codes to machine language code(i.e in 0's and 1's format).It is not directly run as we take the help of OS to execute our code in processor.
The out put of this stage known as object code.

**4.Linker**
It give the final executable code which is going to be run in our machine. The output of this stage is known as executable code. Which is a combination of object code and supporting files.
The supporting files may be user defined function definitions ,predefined library function definitions ...etc.